# Why doesn't the prime in $\sum_n'$ sit flush against the summation symbol?

Tags: bug, mathjax

The TeX snippets $\sum_n'$ `\sum_n'` and $\sum_n^\prime$ `\sum_n^\prime` should (as with all things TeX, barring trickery) be typeset the same; specifically, they should both look like the latter, as tested in an external compiler.  Why does the former look like ${\sum_n}'$ `{\sum_n}'`?

I include a picture of what this all looks like to me, in case anyone it renders differently for anyone else.  I am using Firefox 123.0 on macOS 14.2.1, with the HTML-CSS renderer.

[image: Firefox output of the post]

It looks substantially the same on Safari 17.2.1, also with HTML-CSS:

[image: Safari output of the post]

It looks absolutely hideous on Chrome 120.0.6099, also with HTML-CSS:

[image: Chrome output of the post]

Comment: This is a MathJax bug.  It will be fixed in v4, but StackExchange is still using v2.7.5 (current version 2 is v2.7.9), so won't benefit from that.  As for Chrome, it looks like the sigma is not being scaled as it should.  Perhaps there is a Chrome preference setting that is interfering with font scaling?

Comment: @DavideCervone, [re](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5893/why-doesnt-the-prime-in-sum-n-sit-flush-against-the-summation-symbol#comment30745_5893), thanks!  I know you have brought up this issue of the outdated MathJax version often, and, of course, it's impossible for bug fixes to have any effect if the version is frozen.  Who, if anyone, can make the decision to upgrade MO's MathJax instance?

Comment: I don't know who decides these things.  My previous contacts at SE are no longer there, so I don't have anyone to recommend contacting.  I'm not sure what the best route is for that.

Comment: @LSpice I will just point out that these posts are marked as (status-review): [Are there plans to switch to the current version of MathJax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385913) and [MathJax out of date](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35316).